# Kotlin - Get difference between datetimes in seconds

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, datetime

Is there any way, to get the difference between two datetimes in seconds?

For example
First datetime: 2022-04-25 12:09:10
Second datetime: 2022-05-24 02:46:21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dedicated class for that - [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) ([the same in Android doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/time/Duration)).

> A time-based amount of time, such as '34.5 seconds'.
> This class models a quantity or amount of time in terms of seconds and nanoseconds. It can be accessed using other duration-based units, such as minutes and hours. In addition, the DAYS unit can be used and is treated as exactly equal to 24 hours, thus ignoring daylight savings effects. See Period for the date-based equivalent to this class.

Here is example usage:

```kotlin
        val date1 = LocalDateTime.now()
        val date2 = LocalDateTime.now()

        val duration = Duration.between(date1, date2)

        val asSeconds: Long = duration.toSeconds()
        val asMinutes: Long = duration.toMinutes()
```

Comment: How can i insert a specific date like described in the question, indestead of using "LocalDateTime.now()"?

Comment: Are you using strings? `val date: String = "2022-04-25 12:09:10"`? To be honest, it is a bad practice, you should use dedicated objects. `LocalDateTime` has dedicated method to parse a string `public static LocalDateTime parse(CharSequence text)` or `public static LocalDateTime parse(CharSequence text, DateTimeFormatter formatter)` https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/string-to-date

Comment: Also, please, read about differences between LocalDateTime and DateTime and Instant

Answer (score 1):

If your date types are in the `java.time` package, in other words, are inheritors of `Temporal`: Use the [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) class.

```kotlin
val diffSeconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(date1, date2)
```

Note that this can result in a negative value, so do take its absolute value (`abs`) if necessary.

Comment: Does it compute difference between unix timestamps?